# Generating multiple 'requests' based on form selections - PHP - CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have a CakePHP form that lets a user select a variety of parameters.  What I want to do is let them select multiple choices on a few different parameters, and then turn these into multiple submissions.  My CakePHP model is called 'Requests' so ideally what I want to do is have the user be able to create multiple requests through one form submission - essentially a 'cross-product' of the options they choose.

I don't want/need anyone to write code for me but if someone could help me think this problem through and give me a few pointers in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In  PHP is impossible to a Form execute multiple actions.
This is possible using requests by AJAX.
CAKEPHP offers the JSHELPER that help you (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) or you can do it manually using ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you use various models you can import them using `App::uses` to create multiple requests to multiple models ***on the same action***.

Att

Comment: Thanks. I should add that I'm stuck on CakePHP 1.1 (long story - this is on a shared server with lots of internal sites, there are lots of shared files, and I'm not allowed to upgrade).  Hopefully the JS Helper in 1.1 will work.  I do plan to make all the requests be the same model.  Right now my Controller takes the form data and saves it to the database using $this->Request->save($this->data) and performing some other tasks.  How can I get it to save multiple 'instances' of my model?

Comment: What you wanna do more specific??? save many times in the same model?? I dont understand what you really want...

Comment: Sorry, still new to this.  I want to have one form - but based on the selections the user makes - say they make 3 selections in one multi-select, and 2 in another - I want my controller to be able to take the data and form 6 requests that get saved in the database as six different 'instances' of my model.  Sorry if my terminology is a bit off.

Comment: I see now that I probably should say 'records' where I said 'instances.'  With more searching it seems that I need to use something called saveAll and format my input into an array before saving it.  However, it looks like CakePHP 1.1 does not appear to have saveAll(). If you have any other ideas (or if I'm completely off-base) I would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for 'multistep form' ? At this link is how to make it in cakephp 2.x : http://www.ergotaxio.net/2012/09/09/multistep-forms-in-cakephp/